# How do I compile OpenCV + CUDA on Mac OSX (I tried cmake and a makefile)?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, cuda, makefile

I've seen this asked plenty of times but can't find an answer that works.  I'm trying to compile my project yet keep getting a bunch of x86-64 errors.  I know I'm probably going to get downvoted since it has several similar questions (non working for me), but I need to get it figured out.  Thanks for the help.

Here's the makefile + errors that I keep getting.

```
LINK_FILES=`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++0x -O3 -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include

all: HW2

HW2: main.o Union_Find.o Kernals.o
    g++ -o hw2 main.o Union_Find.o Kernals.o ${LINK_FILES}

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp ${CXX_FLAGS}

Union_Find.o: Union_Find.hpp Union_Find.cpp
    g++ -c Union_Find.cpp ${CXX_FLAGS}

Kernals.o: Kernals.hpp Kernals.cu
    nvcc -c Kernals.cu

clean:
    rm *.o hw2
```

These errors are what I get when I compile with this makefile.

```
g++ -c main.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++0x -O3 -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include
g++ -c Union_Find.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++0x -O3 -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include
nvcc -c Kernals.cu
g++ -o hw2 main.o Union_Find.o Kernals.o `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::ostream::put(char)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::ostream::flush()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::ostream::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in main.o
      __GLOBAL__I_a in Union_Find.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in Kernals.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in main.o
      __GLOBAL__I_a in Union_Find.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in Kernals.o
  "std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::_M_insert_unique(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > const&) in Union_Find.o
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::_M_insert_unique(std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > const&) in Union_Find.o
  "std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::_M_insert_unique(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > const&) in Union_Find.o
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) in Union_Find.o
  "std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::_M_insert_unique(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > const&) in Union_Find.o
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::_M_insert_unique(std::pair<int const, std::pair<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > const&) in Union_Find.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "___cudaRegisterFatBinary", referenced from:
      __sti____cudaRegisterAll_42_tmpxft_0000a8de_00000000_6_Kernals_cpp1_ii_f3b8c2ed() in Kernals.o
  "___cudaRegisterFunction", referenced from:
      __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void**) in Kernals.o
  "___cudaUnregisterFatBinary", referenced from:
      __cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil() in Kernals.o
  "_cudaConfigureCall", referenced from:
      callKernal(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, unsigned char*, int, int) in Kernals.o
  "_cudaFree", referenced from:
      callKernal(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, unsigned char*, int, int) in Kernals.o
  "_cudaLaunch", referenced from:
      cudaError (anonymous namespace)::cudaLaunch<char>(char*) in Kernals.o
  "_cudaMalloc", referenced from:
      callKernal(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, unsigned char*, int, int) in Kernals.o
  "_cudaMemcpy", referenced from:
      callKernal(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, unsigned char*, int, int) in Kernals.o
  "_cudaSetupArgument", referenced from:
      __device_stub__Z9firstPassPhiiPi(unsigned char*, int, int, int*) in Kernals.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [HW2] Error 1
```

When I use a cmake I'm using this CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project( hw2 )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_definitions(-DHAVE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD -DHAVE_UNISTD_H)
#SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3 -stdlib=libstdc++")
#SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3 -stdlib=libstdc++")
SET(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-Xcompiler -stdlib=libstdc++; -Xlinker -stdlib=libstdc++")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( hw2 main.cpp Union_Find.cpp Kernals.cu )
target_link_libraries( hw2 ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

And I get this error:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hw2.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hw2.dir/Union_Find.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable hw2
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "callKernal(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&, unsigned char*, int, int)", referenced from:
      Union_Find::Union_Find(cv::Mat&) in Union_Find.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [hw2] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hw2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs results in:

```
-I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

Comment: What does `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` give?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist  -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab

Comment: In your Makefile's rules for the source files (for instance, `g++ -c main.cpp ${CXX_FLAGS}`), I don't see a `-o main.o` switch. This means it will produce an `a.out` file in the current directory, not what you want.

Comment: -c Creates a .o file for main.o.  I don't need to declare it as such.

Comment: Odd, I must be recalling wrong or maybe it's the antique GCC I'm using. Alright, check that the libraries installed under `/opt/local/lib` really are x86_64 dynamic libraries, using something like `file /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib`. Do you get something that ressembles `/opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

Comment: Yep exactly as that: file /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

Comment: OpenCV doesn't look like the problem then... I'm looking at your Makefile again. The invocation of `g++` that links everything together is missing `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++0x`, but the compile commands have it. I also don't know why you have two `-std=` specifications. As for the `callKernal` error in the CMakeList, it's likely a spelling mistake - confirm you used `callKernel` everywhere.

Comment: I thought that too with the cmake.  I don't see anything misspelled or different for that function.  The weird thing is that it almost doesn't see it.  It doesn't look like cmake is even compiling it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62551/discussion-between-iwillnotexist-idonotexist-and-kevin-melkowski).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to thank Iwillnotexist Idonotexist for his huge help with this.  We worked towards getting everything linked together on a Mac OSX.  For the Makefile I had to take out the -stdlib=libstdc++ flag and add in the linker flags: -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart (Similarly with the cmake file).  A working example of both the Makefile and CMakeLists.txt files can be found below.

Makefile:

```
CUDA_FLAGS=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart
LINK_FILES=`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -std=c++0x -O3 -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include   

all: HW2

HW2: main.o Union_Find.o Kernals.o 
    g++ -o hw2 main.o Union_Find.o Kernals.o ${LINK_FILES} ${CUDA_FLAGS}

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp ${CXX_FLAGS}

Union_Find.o: Union_Find.hpp Union_Find.cpp
    g++ -c Union_Find.cpp ${CXX_FLAGS}

Kernals.o: Kernals.hpp Kernals.cu
    nvcc -c Kernals.cu

clean:
    rm *.o hw2
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
project( hw2 )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

add_definitions(-DHAVE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD -DHAVE_UNISTD_H)
SET(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart" )

cuda_compile(Kernel Kernals.cu)
add_executable( hw2 main.cpp Union_Find.cpp ${Kernel} )
target_link_libraries( hw2 ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CUDA_LIBS} )
```

Comment: +1, Upvoted both. I'll try and remember this, I might be doing OpenCV CUDA work too in the near future.